# VBA - Change all Word Footer in folder - not more compatible

Tags: vba, ms-word

For years I have used the VBA code below to change the footer in all Word files in a folder (including subfolders).

It works pretty well, but only to the version Word 2003! Now I'm using Word 2010 and if I start the code I get the error:

> Run-time error 5111. The command is not available on this platform

```
Private Sub Image16_Click()

    Dim Suchpfad, oPath
    Folder = BrowseForFolder("Sélectionnez le dossier où les fichiers doivent être traitées")
    If Len(Folder) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Vous n'avez pas sélectionné un dossier!"
        Exit Sub
    Else
        'ChangeFileOpenDirectory Folder
        oPath = Folder
        'MsgBox oPath
    End If


'**** Fußzeilen löschen
    Pfad = oPath
    With Application.FileSearch
        .LookIn = Pfad
        .SearchSubFolders = True
        .FileType = msoFileTypeWordDocuments
        .Execute
        For i = 1 To .FoundFiles.Count
            strName = .FoundFiles(i)
            WordBasic.DisableAutoMacros
            Documents.Open FileName:=strName
            Dim Abschnitt As Section
                For Each Abschnitt In ActiveDocument.Sections
                    For j = 1 To 3
                        On Error Resume Next
                        Abschnitt.Footers(j).Range.Delete
                    Next j
                Next

                If ActiveWindow.View.SplitSpecial <> wdPaneNone Then
        ActiveWindow.Panes(2).Close
    End If
    If ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.Type = wdNormalView Or ActiveWindow. _
        ActivePane.View.Type = wdOutlineView Then
        ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.Type = wdPrintView
    End If
    ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.SeekView = wdSeekCurrentPageHeader
    If Selection.HeaderFooter.IsHeader = True Then
        ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.SeekView = wdSeekCurrentPageFooter
    Else
        ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.SeekView = wdSeekCurrentPageHeader
    End If
    Selection.WholeStory
    Selection.Font.Name = "Verdana"
    Selection.Font.Size = 7
    Selection.TypeText Text:="First Line of Footer"
    Selection.TypeParagraph
    Selection.Font.Size = 6
    Selection.TypeText Text:="Second Line of Footer"
    ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.SeekView = wdSeekMainDocument

            ActiveDocument.Save
            ActiveDocument.Close
        Next
    End With
MsgBox "Operation done in " & Pfad & " !!!"

End Sub
```

I can't figure out this problem and I hope that somebody has a solution.

Comment: Application.FileSearch is not  assisted after 2007.

Comment: Hello @Dy.Lee, thanks for the infos. Do you know if existe an equivalent for Word 2007 and higher?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you will need a recursive folder parsing routine. This should work.

```
Public Sub RecursiveFolderParse(Folder, dictFiles As Object, sExt As String)
  Dim SubFolder As Variant
  Dim File As Variant

  For Each SubFolder In Folder.SubFolders
    RecursiveFolderParse SubFolder, dictFiles, sExt
  Next

  For Each File In Folder.Files
    If Right$(File.Name, Len(sExt)) = sExt Then
      If Not dictFiles.Exists(File.Path) Then
        dictFiles.Add File.Path, 1
      End If
    End If
  Next
End Sub
```

Then to use this routine, here is your main subroutine where you process each file accordingly:

```
Public Sub ProcessAllFiles()
  Dim sFolder As String
  Dim dictFiles As Object
  Dim FileSystem As Object
  Dim vKeys As Variant
  Dim sFilename As Variant
  Dim sExt As String

  ' define your folder and the extension to look for
  sFolder = "C:\Test"
  sExt = "zip"

  Set dictFiles = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
  Set FileSystem = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

  RecursiveFolderParse FileSystem.GetFolder(sFolder), dictFiles, sExt
  vKeys = dictFiles.Keys

  For Each sFilename In vKeys

    ' process file code goes here
    MsgBox sFilename

  Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Hello braX, thank you very much for your help. I'll try it ASAP. cheers